# looking for the first time specific characters appear

Tags: vba, ms-access

In vba I am openening a table from access with a column that look like the following:

```
1300nm11-53-0202 0302.SOR
```

I would like to look for the very first time "nm" is found in the string and write everything that is before that into a variable "strGolfLengte" (so In this case strGolflengte would be "1300")

NB:
I can't be sure that there won't be several nm's in the string, I just want to look for the first time they are found.

NB2:
The string before nm could be "n" characters, in all cases, I want the full lenght (n) of the string written in strGolflengte

Comment: If the string does not contain "nm" the file is invalid and should be dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `instr()' function like this:

```
strGolfLengte = left(myLine,instr(1,myLine,"nm",1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the easiest way to do this:

```
strGolfLengte = Split(myLine,"nm")(0)
```